# What is the root cause of 'out of shared memory ' issue?

Tags: postgresql, shared-buffers

I'm having 'out of shared memory' issue in PostgreSQL 13.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (The database has 41G data), first, it suggested me to increase max_locks_per_transaction.

After increasing max_locks_per_transaction to 1024, I still get 'out of shared memory', but now it suggests:

```
ERROR:  out of shared memory
HINT:  You might need to increase max_pred_locks_per_transaction.
```

It seems very confusing to me. So my question:

- Why does max_pred_locks_per_transaction affect on shared_memory ?
- The shared_buffers is already 4GB, should I increase it ?
- The 'out of shared memory' relates to which: max_locks_per_transaction * (max_connections + max_prepared_transactions) or shared_buffers ?

Thank you all.

Comment: Is the query execution plan using parallel query? Are you using the `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation level?

Answer (score 1):

These error messages indicate that the hash table to store locks has been exhausted. This table is located in the shared memory segment and has a constant size, [determined](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_16_1/src/backend/storage/lmgr/lock.c#L57) when the database starts as:

```
max_locks_per_transaction * (
  (max_connections + autovacuum_max_workers + 1 +
     max_worker_processes + max_wal_senders) # this is MaxBackends
  + max_prepared_transactions
)
```

Not related to `shared_buffers` at all. This and many other structures in shared memory structures are added in addition to the amount required to accommodate shared_buffers.

Look at your [pg_locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-locks.html) to find out exactly what data the lock table stores in your database.

Common reasons:

- excessive use of partitioning, when a query on a table with 5 indexes instead of 6 locks requires >6000 locks due to the existing 1000 partitions
- widespread use of serializable transaction isolation. Predicate locks are stored in pg_locks as mode=SIReadLock; there can be a lot of them
- many [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS)

Comment: It seems that max_pred_locks_per_transaction is not in max_locks_per_transaction * (
  (max_connections + autovacuum_max_workers + 1 +
     max_worker_processes + max_wal_senders) # this is MaxBackends
  + max_prepared_transactions
). So why the error message suggests increasing max_pred_locks_per_transaction ?

Comment: Damn, the second error message is really about another hash table. https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_13_3/src/backend/storage/lmgr/predicate.c#L57 This hash table is only about Serializable Snapshot Isolation.